# Laravel problems when sending email

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

When I'm trying to send an email using the swiftmailer in laravel I get the folowing error: "Missing argument 2 for UsersController::{closure}()".

My code is below:

```
Mail::send('emails.default', array('key' => Config::get('settings.WELCOMEMAIL')), function($message, $mail, $subject = 'Welcome!')
{
    $message->to($mail)->subject($subject);
});
```

It's really weird though. The $mail variable contains a valid email address and I'm not using the UsersController at all in this script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must pass only the `$message` to the closure. Any additional variable must be passed down with the `use` keyword:

```
Mail::send('emails.default', array('key' => Config::get('settings.WELCOMEMAIL')), function($message) use($mail, $subject)
{
    $subject = empty($subject) ? 'Welcome!' : $subject;
    $message->to($mail)->subject($subject);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and correct answer! Laravel is great but I find that the documentation sometimes lacks important details.